# Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' in Apache/PHP

Tags: php, apache, openssl, phpmailer

In regard to using `extension=openssl` with PHP/Apache, I am getting `"Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl'"` error message when using PHP 7.2.15 with Apache 2.4.37 on win10/X64 laptop.

I can stop Apache and switch to PHP 7.1.28 on the same computer and I do not get the error message. I have tried numerous suggestions from similarly asked questions but still stuck! Obviously, there is some subtle difference between PHP versions?

> [21-Apr-2019 03:26:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' (tried: C:\PHP\ext\openssl (The specified module could not be found.), C:\PHP\ext\php_openssl.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: could you please check the path `C:\PHP\ext\php_openssl.dll` to see whether it exists or not?

Comment: Try running `phpinfo()` from a PHP script and see if it says anything about openssl.

Comment: In both php.ini files I have extension_dir = "c:\php\ext" and I have the line "extension=openssl" uncommented in version 7.2.15. I also have the line "extension=php_openssl.dll" uncommented in version 7.1.28. In version 7.1.28 I see OpenSSL in PHPInfo(). In version 7.2.15 OpenSSL is missing in PHPInfo().